# How convert sentence with verb "cut" to passive

Tags: passive-voice

How to convert this sentence

> I cut the trees

to Present indefinite Passive voice. I am doubtful about this

> the trees are cut by me

Am i right or wrong?

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: That's right. But I don't like the passive version. The active version isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trees are cut by me is correct.

The trees which were the object become the subject.
Cut becomes are cut.
I becomes me with the preposition by to indicate that I am the agent.